# editing and adding records blocking in multiuser mode

Tags: ms-access

Im using msaccess 2010 on Windows 7 and  faced the following problem: in multiuser mode editind ALL of record  and adding new record blocked in all forms when some user working with database, in single user mode all work perfect.

1. Database is separated to front-end and back-end parts. Back-end part is located on network drive in directory with full right for all users, copies of front-end part are on users computers.
2. In client settings: Default open mode - shared, Default record locking - no lock, open database by record-level locking -on
3. In forms properties - allow add, edit, delete - yes, block records - no.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, this should just work. There are several things to check.

First up, the shared folder where the data part exists needs FULL rights. That means create file rights, and delete file rights. When a access database is opened, then it creates a 2nd file in that same back end folder. That 2nd file is how access handles and manages multi-user operations. If users don't have create file rights, and delete file rights to that folder, then that multi-user locking file cannot be created, and thus in most cases, the result is a read-only database.

Next up, do check your forms. You do NOT want the settings to lock the WHOLE table. That is this setting:

[image]

So, if you set above to "all records", then of course only one user can edit that table the form is based on.

That setting is a per form by form basis, and thus you do NOT have a global wide setting for this. And you should ALSO check reports - they should have all no records, since you can lock a whole table for some special reports - and in 99% of cases, you don't need nor want that.

But, check the shared folder rights. The users need read/write AND ALSO file create, and file delete rights. If they don't have such rights to that folder, then in most cases you find the result is a read-only database.